# I cannot add web module to IntellIj 9 Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

I wanted to add a JSP to my project and I think this is most conveniently done by adding a web module.  Unfortunately when I do File->New Module the only types available are Java Module and Android Module.

I have tried turning on all likely plug-ins but no Web (or other module type, except Android) Module type appears.

Help About says it's IntelliJ 9.0.2 Ultimate (Personal License).  The Register page appears to have a satisfactory license key.

Running on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the Java Module, and if your `JEE integration plugin` is enabled, you will be able to select the "web facet" later in your module creation.

You could also install the maven plugin and create a maven module based on the `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype.